# Trouble connecting to Oracle database with sqlplus and OS authentication

Tags: oracle, powershell, active-directory

I am a read-only user to an oracle database, and the DBA gave me two accounts, one with a specific user name and password, and another with OS authentication. The OS authentication is supposed to let me connect by authenticating with my active directory user account that I use to login to my laptop, where I am then running sqlplus.

I can connect and start querying just fine with this command, which shows it is picking up my tnsnames file:

```
sqlplus username/password@database
```

However, the version to connect with OS authentication doesn't work:

```
sqlplus /@database

ERROR: ORA-01017: invalid username/password; logon denied
```

**Am I doing something obviously wrong?** I checked in powershell that my user and domain name are the user and domain name that was set up for OS authentication for this database.

I did another test, this time using powershell to do the connection and again with my AD login that should work:

```
Add-Type -Path "C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Oracle.ManagedDataAccess\Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.dll"
    
#This connection string works for the normal authenticated account
$connectionString = "User Id=$username;Password=$password;Data Source=$datasource"
    
#But this one gives me ORA-01017 invalid username/password
$connectionString = "User Id=/;Data Source=$datasource"
    
$connection = New-Object Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client.OracleConnection($connectionString)
$connection.open()
```

I also made sure that SQLNET.AUTHENTICATION_SERVICES= (NTS) is in the sqlnet.ora file

Any thoughts?

Comment: Have you asked the DBA about this? Anyway, Oracle connection problems are better on-topic at DBA.SE. Since the error is reported even via sqlplus (a native Oracle tool), it's something on the infra or user account. As neither is about programming, the question is off-topic at SO.

Answer (score 0):

When you connect from putty or shell you need to login to the sever first using OS authentication. Then you can use sqlplus authentication to connect sqlplus.